# SQLAlchemy filter if JSON field contains a value

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a table represent by this class

```
from sqlalchemy import JSON


class Mytable(Base):
    myfield = JSON
```

The `myfield` column will contain JSON arrays.

I'd like to select only rows where the `myfield` column contains a specific value `foo`, how do I do this ? (I am on Mysql 8.0 but I assume the solution might be the same for all database types)

What I have tried so far

- Using the `in` operation

```py
session.query(Mytable).filter("foo" in Mytable.myfield)
```

This returns the error `NotImplementedError: Operator 'contains' is not supported on this expression`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer by rerunning examples I thought would not work, and correcting a typo :)

Using the `JSON_CONTAINS` method through `sqlalchemy.func` works for my case.

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

session.query(MyTable).filter(func.json_contains(Mytable.myfield, '"foo"', "$"))
```

(Note the double quotes around `foo`)